# React - dropdown menu - styled component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am making a dropdown component using styled-component.

I think everything will be clear from the attached image.

First image is when I clicked dropdown menu, and second menu is showing that the dropdown menu makes a space at the bottom of the page. So what I want to know is how I would go about making the drop down menu open upwards.

Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: First of all, of course it's possible. However, do you have a specific question? Stackoverflow isn't a tutorial site - your question should be very finite, not a general "How do I make a dropdown?" sort of question.

Comment: @yoursweater don't you know how to do that?